# Post Data to php just after the html page is load

Tags: php, jquery, html

I would like to send a data to php but i don't know why it doesn't work

Here is my code

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<title>web </title>
<body>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
      $.post("loadWebGenerator.php",
        {
            data: "received"
        }
      );
    })
</script>
<form oninput="getSubjectList()">
    <input list="subjectName">
        <datalist id="subjectName">
        </datalist>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

php

```
include('../Sql.php');
$received = $_post['data'];
file_put_contents("log.txt",$received);
```

Thank you

Comment: It should be `$_POST[data]` instead of `$_post['data']` as `$_POST` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

The variable names are case sensitive.

The code should be like this:

```
include('../Sql.php');
$received = $_POST['data'];
file_put_contents("log.txt",$received);
```

By the way, it's better to make it a bit more reliable:

```
include('../Sql.php');
if (!empty($_POST['data']) {
  $received = $_POST['data'];
  file_put_contents("log.txt",$received);
}
```